# Compare 2 (epoch) times, if one is newer then the other do

Tags: android, date, epoch

Goal is to compare 2 times, 1 from android device and the other provided from database server (in epoch), http://www.epochconverter.com/
If one time is newer then the other, a value should be added (marked as new in a listview, newItem = true;).
The provided times are already converted to string outputs (today, day of month, yesterday) using (simpledateformat).

What would be the easiest way to compare the two (epoch)times 'before' the conversion to strings? I already searched a bit on stackoverflow but i`m insecure which one would fit my goal the best and quickest.

```
private String getDateString(final Date d) {
    if (d == null)
        return "";

    int[] elements1, elements2;

    elements1 = getDateElements(System.currentTimeMillis()); <-- current time
    elements2 = getDateElements(d.getTime()); <-- db time

    if (elements1[0] == elements2[0] && elements1[1] == elements2[1]) {
        if (elements1[2] == elements2[2])
            return "Today";

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        elements1 = getDateElements(c.getTimeInMillis());

        if (elements1[2] == elements2[2])
            return "Yesterday";

    }
    return Util.formatDate(d);
}
```

---

```
public static String formatDate(final long dt) {
    return formatDate(new Date(dt));
}

public static String formatDate(final Date date) {
    final DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,
            DateFormat.SHORT);
    return df.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `after` method in the Date class? Something like  `new Date().after(db time)`...

Comment: Hi Diego,
Thx, not yet, i first want to make sure i`m catching the correct data, as everything is comming from SQL db and i`m not into SQL but i think i`m on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the comparison you want to make is, you already have everything you need:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long dbTime = d.getTime();

if (dbTime < currentTime) {
    // Do something
}
```

Alternatively, as suggested by Diego in the comments, you could use the [`Date#after`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) and `before` methods:

```
public boolean isInFuture(Date d) {
    return d.after(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam,
This could indeed be a solution. You think this could work to keep it in the GetDateString function?
I was more thinking at a seperate function. As mentioned i`m looking for feedback for the right approach. The value`s are comming from a SQL db base and i`m not into SQL unfortunately.

Comment: You know, I guess I didn't read the rest of the method. Putting it into a separate method would work, but it's up to you. All you're doing is comparing two `long` values. I'll update the answer with a method you could use.

Comment: Hi Adam. Nice, looking good. I'll try when I'm home, still @work. Thx again for the efforts I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi Adam,
Unfortunately doesn`t work, i declared currentTime and dbTime as private long. Then inserted your mentioned code in the GetDateString, Log.d("CURRENT TIME: ", String.valueOf(currentTime));
Log.d("DBTIME: ", String.valueOf(dbTime));
Gives both 0

Comment: If they're both 0, then you never assigned a value to them.

Comment: Adam i think i found the problem, the time is communicated as 'string' (Today, 6:35, Yesterday 10:45pm etc) and no epoch time. Is there a way to convert them back to a usable date/time format?

Comment: Maybe access the SQL db and get the times there? Unfortunately i`m not into SQL but could this be a solution? So i would not know such a command.